# Detecting Barcodes with Android vision API

Tags: android, google-vision

I'm trying to use the google android vision API to detect bar codes. The camera frames are generated by an external UVCCamera, which provides `java.nio.DirectByteBuffer` as frames. I was trying to use the method `public Frame.Builder setImageData (ByteBuffer data, int width, int height, int format)` to resolve bar codes by passing `java.nio.ByteBufferArray` objects as the bytebuffer. Pixel format of the UVCCamera frames are in NV21 format. But I'm not getting any result, no errors or exceptions.

***Configuraions***:

```
SDK: 23
google pla service: 33
vision api: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
```

But in the [samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader), what is passed into the method is a `java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer` (after wrapping the byte array using `ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)`)

Following is a sample code I used[note that it is a simplified version of the code, which actually runs on a thread]:

```
public void process(ByteBuffer mPendingFrameData) 
{
    byte[] arr = new byte[frame.remaining()];
    frame.get(arr);
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap( arr );

    Frame outputFrame = null;

    while (true) 
    {
        try
        {
            mPendingFrameData.clear();
            outputFrame = new Frame.Builder().setImageData( buf, 640, 480, ImageFormat.NV21).build();

            if( detector.isOperational() )
            {
                SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(outputFrame);

                if(barcodes.size()!=0)
                {
                    Barcode barcodeValue = barcodes.valueAt(0);
                    System.out.println(barcodeValue.rawValue);
                }
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I created another buffer is to create a ByteBufferArray.

Can anyone please let me know what is the part I'm missing here?

Comment: DirectByteBuffer should be fine, although be careful to account for the offset properly.  My guess is that you are passing in an image format that it isn't expected.  The pixel data should lead with the Y channel -- essentially a grayscale image with one byte per pixel.

Comment: I've edited the question with more details. As you've mentioned pixel formats of the ByteBuffer and the image resolving formats are the same: NV21. before passing it to the method I'm resetting the buffer (by calling clear()), which doesn't any changes to the content but the current position is reset back to the start of the buffer, the value of the buffer limit is made equal to the capacity.

Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Try checking "detector.isOperational()" to see if the underlying barcode library is available.  If your device is too low on storage, that would block Google Play services from acquiring that library.

Comment: I tested the code with isOperational() checked, but still i'm not getting any results I've updated the code and the description. Could you please have a look at it?